# Running elevated cmd.exe in batch script with elevate.exe

Tags: batch-file

I am writing a dos batch file for windows7 and it has many commands which need elevated access to run. For elevation I am using elevate.exe. I am doing like below -

```
set Elevation=elevate -wait cmd.exe /c 
%Elevation% "cd /d %CD% && xcopy /E /Y ...."
%Elevation% "cd /d %CD% && command 2 .."
%Elevation% "cd /d %CD% && command 3 .."
%Elevation% "cd /d %CD% && command 4 .."
.....
```

My script calls elevate for cmd and then `cd /d %CD%` for each command as elevate changes the working path to /system32 I am forced to change the directory every time I run elevate. It also prompts user for "UAC" dialog for each elevate command, so for ten such command UAC prompts will come 10 times :cry:. Commands I am using are mix of DOS command(like xcopy, diskpart etc) and some other 3rd party executable. So there is two problem for which I need some help-

1. How to call elevate for cmd.exe once and run rest of the command in same elevated console.
2. How to change working directory once instead with every command. I think solution to first one will take care of this also.

Any help is most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a second batch file with all your commands in it and then run it elevated.

**NOTE**: I changed `%CD%` to `C:\YourFolder` because `%CD%` is the current directory...it doesn't make sense to change to it because you're already in it.

### SECOND.BAT (name this whatever you want)

```
cd /d C:\YourFolder
xcopy /E /Y ....
command 2 ..
command 3 ..
command 4 ..
```

From your original batch file, do this:

```
set Elevation=elevate -wait cmd.exe /c 
%Elevation% "C:\YourFolder\SECOND.BAT"
```

Comment: I liked your proposal but because of legacy reason it is not allowed to introduce new script file in that source code.

Comment: How do you call your original batch file? Can you run it with `elevate` so you don't need to elevate each command inside?